# Include with str_replace function?

Tags: php, include, echo, str-replace

I want to create a page with include function. This page should to grab another site and can change text or code with this function str_replace. I hope that it would be possible. I have written this code, but unfortunately it does not work:

```
<?php
$text = include('http://www.example.com/index.html');
$text = str_replace("<div id=\"hercss\">Hello.</div>", "<div id=\"mycss\">Welcome!</div>", $text);
echo $text;
?>
```

Maybe you have a solution? It would be fully appreciated by you.

Comment: If you're wanting to get it from another site, you need to use `file_get_contents()` or `CURL`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.example.com/index.html";
$text = file_get_contents($url);

$text = str_replace("<div id=\"hercss\">Hello.</div>", "<div id=\"mycss\">Welcome!</div>", $text);
echo $text;
?>
```

Include only works with relative links I believe? The function `file_get_contents` works across domains

Comment: For this to work you need to be sure that `allow_url_fopen = On` in php.ini

Comment: It does not work somehow. Because I've tried to insert another code. But it does not work. Here is example code:

<code><?php
    $url = "http://www.coolsport.tv/kiwi2.html";
    $text = file_get_contents($url);
    
    $text = str_replace(" top.location.href=\"http://coolsport.tv\"", " top.location.href=\"http://yahoo.de\"", $text);
    echo $text;
    ?></code>

Comment: try $url = "http://www.coolsport.tv/kiwi2.html"; I believe that it doesn't work as it is redirecting to www.

Comment: No more error messages, only it don't works. Can you give me your skype, so we can to talk faster..?! Thanks :)